# using __block with self

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

I know there are a few ways to do this. But I want to check that the way I have done it isn't causing a leak.

I have a block in my project (using ARC) and to prevent a retain cycle I have done the following

```
 id __block blockSelf = self;
```

and then inside the block replaced self with blockSelf. Is this a good coding practice

Cheers

Comment: Nice find. the only thing I will say is that it doesn't use ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will still retain an object of self inside the block - I do the following:

```
__weak SomeObject *weakSelf = self;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577154/how-can-a-weakly-retained-block-cause-a-retain-cycle-when-capturing-self) too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheers I think you way is a better way of doing it. I ran the profiler using my above code and didn't get any leaks. I not entirely sure what __block will do in this instance

Comment: and here a link for the Docu Bookmark list: http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#arcblocks

Comment: based on this link it appears weak is the way to go if using ARC

Comment: yes weak for iOS 5 or __unsafe_unretained (iOS 4, where __weak is not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

For MRC,

```
__block id blockSelf = self;
```

will not retain 'self'.

However, for ARC, it doesn't work. You have to use:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
```